# PWA stored in Azure - The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain')

Tags: azure-storage, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm building my first custom service-worker.js and I encountered this error.

I'm using Vue + PWA (workbox)
registerServiceWorker.js :

```
import { register } from "register-service-worker";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  console.log("service worker won't be registerd for now");
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log("App is being served from cache by a service worker.");
    },
    registered() {
      console.log("Service worker has been registered.");
    },
    cached() {
      console.log("Content has been cached for offline use.");
    },
    updatefound() {
      console.log("New content is downloading.");
    },
    updated() {
      console.log("New content is available; please refresh.");
    },
    offline() {
      console.log(
        "No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode."
      );
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error("Error during service worker registration:", error);
    }
  });
}
```

service-worker.js :

```
console.log("Hello from service-worker.js");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get rid of this error I just changed the Content Type of the service-worker.js file (using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer -> right click -> properties -> ContentType)
[image]

PS: let me know if you know how to automate this.

Comment: and automated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62155272/azure-cli-edit-content-type-file-property/62163691#62163691