# Azure CLI edit Content Type file property

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azure-storage-files

I'm trying to update Content Type property of a file located in my Azure $web blob container using Azure CLI. I'm trying to do this because it's wrongly set and my service-worker.js (for my PWA) needs to have "application/javascript" instead of "text/plain; charset=utf-8" in order to be registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Azure cli, you should use [az storage blob update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-update).

The sample code:

```
az storage blob update --container-name xxx --name xxx --account-key xxx --account-name xxx --content-type "application/javascript"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this using Azure Pipelines:

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  displayName: "Azure Storage - copy new files"
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/*'
    azureSubscription: 'johnykes-PAYG(44df419f-b455-4c4d-a8f8-c2a5fd479f10)'
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: 'johnykeschatfrontend'
    ContainerName: '$web'

- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  displayName: "Azure Storage - overwrite .js files with correct Content Type"
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/*.js'
    azureSubscription: 'johnykes-PAYG(44df419f-b455-4c4d-a8f8-c2a5fd479f10)'
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: 'johnykeschatfrontend'
    ContainerName: '$web'
    AdditionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: '--content-type "application/javascript"'
```

Please let me know if you find a way of doing using the Azure CLI or in my way but recursively (for all .js files) or in any other way.